# Why when my Python3 .pyw file is run from Visual Studio Code on Macos it gets "No module named 'PyQt6' but runs ok at macos command line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

.pyw has no problem if I run from terminal command line or by double-clicking with Finder.

BUT in VSC if I select the .pyw and do "Run > Start debug" or "Run > Run Without Debug" it gets the error:

```
/Users/me/.zshrc:export:2: not valid in this context: /Users/me/.zshrc me@Dougs-MacBook-2023 softwarehubgui %  /usr/bin/env /Users/me/PRIMARY/WORK/MOJO/Software/softwarehubgui/.venv/bin/python /Users/me /.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2024.0.1/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/launcher 61817 -- /Users/me/PRIMARY/WO RK/MOJO/Software/softwarehubgui/SoftwareHubGUI.pyw  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/Users/me/PRIMARY/WORK/MOJO/Software/softwarehubgui/SoftwareHubGUI.pyw", line 5, in <module>
    from PyQt6.QtGui import QIcon ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt6' me@Dougs-MacBook-2023 softwarehubgui
```

=== THE .pyw FILE ==========================

```
import os
import signal

from PyQt6.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication
import sys
from include.BaseDialog import BaseDialog

if __name__ == '__main__':
    qapp = QApplication(sys.argv)
    qapp.setWindowIcon(QIcon(f'{sys.path[0]}/include/Icon.png'))


    styleSheet = """
            
        """
    qapp.setStyleSheet(styleSheet)
    app = BaseDialog()
    qapp.aboutToQuit.connect(app.close_program)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, app.close_program)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, app.close_program)
    sys.exit(qapp.exec())
```

Here is path...  (I don't see PyQt in it.)

> dbell@Dougs-Mac softwarehubgui % echo $PATH
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin

Both the macos Terminal window and the Visual Studio Code's terminal window have the same path.

UPDATE   2/12/2024
In response to Tim's suggestion, I found two Python 3.11 versions and for each I selected it and then right-clicked my python .pyw script but each failed and I got the following errors...

1st python selection got this error.......

> me@Dougs-MacBook-2023 softwarehubgui % /Users/me/PRIMARY/WORK/MOJO/Software/softwarehubgui/.venv/bin/p
> ython /Users/me/PRIMARY/WORK/MOJO/Software/softwarehubgui/SoftwareHubGUI.pyw
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/Users/me/PRIMARY/WORK/MOJO/Software/softwarehubgui/SoftwareHubGUI.pyw", line 5, in 
> from PyQt6.QtGui import QIcon
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt6'
> me@Dougs-MacBook-2023 softwarehubgui %

2nd python selection got this error.......

```
me@Dougs-MacBook-2023 softwarehubgui % /usr/local/bin/python3 /Users/me/PRIMARY/WORK/MOJO/Software/sof
twarehubgui/SoftwareHubGUI.pyw
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/PRIMARY/WORK/MOJO/Software/softwarehubgui/SoftwareHubGUI.pyw", line 5, in <module>
    from PyQt6.QtGui import QIcon
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PyQt6/QtGui.abi3.so, 0x0002): Symbol not found: __ZN13QRasterWindow11resizeEventEP12QResizeEvent
  Referenced from: <C8D7E625-2A13-3C34-9DFF-B6656A6F86E7> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PyQt6/QtGui.abi3.so
  Expected in:     <FC67C721-05AD-33BB-A2A8-F70FC3403D7A> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PyQt6/Qt6/lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/A/QtGui
me@Dougs-MacBook-2023 softwarehubgui % 
enter code here
```

Comment: AFAIK pyw files only make sense on Windows, they are fundamentally python files with a different file extension that tells Windows to not show the command prompt while executing the script. In unix like systems (so, including macOS), this is irrelevant, as they do not need an active shell to execute non-gui programs. You probably have some wine/python version installed and that obviously has its own env (for which you don't have installed PyQt). Just rename to the standard `py` extension, as `pyw` wouldn't be valid anyway for macOS.

Comment: To be precise, `pyw` are associated with `pythonw.exe` instead of the default `python.exe` for `py` files. It seems that by default `pythonw` is an alias to the old `python2.7` macOS, which you probably still have installed, but it obviously is a different (and obsolete) version that is not the one you're interested in. In any case, the point remains: don't use the `pyw` extension unless you're on Windows.

Comment: mu..:  my script .pyw works on from macos terminal.  Probably path problem.  I added path to this question.

Comment: This is one of the most commonly asked questions here.  VSCode has its own installation of Python, separate from the one you get at the command line.  You can tell VSCode which Python to use, or you can install PyQt6 through VSCode.

Comment: Tim:  Thank you.  I will learn how to and then tell VSCode to use same Python3 as my macos Terminal command line.

Comment: Tim: How do I tell VSCode to use my MacOS terminal command line Python3 for VSCode debugger?